# Consume Windows hosted WCF from jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, wcf, cross-domain

I'm trying to access a windows hosted WCF from jQuery. I'm unable to access data send to server while using POST. So I used 'GET' and able to post data to server. But the client is not receiving response from server. I'm getting 'Cross-Origin' Request Blocked' error.

jQuery client Code

```
function callWCF() {
var obj = {};
obj.data = "XLGS";
var inputData = JSON.stringify(obj);
var url = 'http://localhost:8733/TestService/GetData?value=' + 'test';
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    data: {},
    //data: { parameters: "{'process':'AutoComplete', 'getall':'false'}" },
    contentType: '',
    dataType: '',
    success: function (httpResponse) {
        alert("Success");
    },
    error: function (httpResponse) {
        alert("Error");
    }
});}
```

WCF service code

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    public string GetData(string value)
    {
        return value + " Response from service";
    }
```

WCF Host configuration

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="TestServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webBehavior">
      <webHttp />
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="TestServiceBehavior" name="WCFAjax.GateWayService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFAjax.IGateWayService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="web" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFAjax.IGateWayService">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/TestService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

<!--<services>
  <service name="WCFAjax.GateWayService">
    <endpoint address=""
      binding="webHttpBinding"
      bindingConfiguration=""
      name="WCFAjax.GateWayService"
      contract="WCFAjax.IGateWayService" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/TestService"/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>-->
<!--<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />-->
```

Ho to resolve it?